# wso2 keystore management - do keystores added to one carbon node get replicated to other nodes?

Tags: wso2

I'm investigating the key management functionality in WSO2 ([see wikidocs](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Key+Stores)).

**Question**: If I use the key management functionality to add a new keystore on one node, does the keystore get replicated to other nodes in the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK in a clustered deployment replication of Keystores is not supported in WSO2 products. Only the files under repository/deployment/server are synchronized. The keystores are not in that directory. So as a work-arround you can add the keystores to that directory and point to them in the relevant config files. Also note that if the setup if a worker manager setup , only manager will be able to commit, so the modifications should be done in the managers node.